# Bigquery replace value in a column based on previous year date condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need help to write a SQL logic in bigquery to replace a value in one column based on a condition as below

FINANCIAL YEAR --> JUL to JUN

How can I make it more dynamic so it rolls over next year

```
Condition --> If version = "ACT" an  DATE is not current year i.e 07-2020 to 06-2021 then replace ACT with ACTA
```

Current:

| Version | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| ACT | 202104 |
| ACT | 202101 |
| ACT | 202006 |
| ACT | 202001 |
| ACT | 202007 |
| ACT | 201903 |
| ACT | 202008 |
| TAR | 202104 |
| TAR | 202101 |
| TAR | 202006 |
| TAR | 202001 |
| TAR | 202007 |
| TAR | 201903 |
| TAR | 202008 |

Output required:

| Version | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| ACT | 202104 |
| ACT | 202101 |
| ACT | 202006 |
| **ACTA** | 202001 |
| ACT | 202007 |
| **ACTA** | 201903 |
| ACT | 202008 |
| TAR | 202104 |
| TAR | 202101 |
| TAR | 202006 |
| TAR | 202001 |
| TAR | 202007 |
| TAR | 201903 |
| TAR | 202008 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If version = "ACT" an  DATE is not current year i.e 07-2020 to 06-2021 then replace ACT with ACTA

You want a `case` expression:

```
select (case when version = 'ACT' and
                  extract(year from date_add(date, interval 6 month)) = extract(year from date_add(current_date, interval 6 month))
             then 'ACTA'
             else version
        end)
```

The logic is to add six months and extract the year to get the fiscal year.  Do the same for the current date.  When these are the same, then the `date` column is in the current fiscal year.

Answer (score 1):

Base on sample data in your question - I assume your data column is just INT64. Consider below then

```
select 
  if(version = 'ACT' and div(date + 93, 100) != extract(year from current_date), 'ACTA', Version) as Version,
  date
from data
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]